# Ruby: puts a variable's value and name

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash of hashes of arrays:

```
hash = Hash.new do |hash, key|
    hash[key] = Hash.new do |hash, key|
        hash[key] = Array.new
    end
end
```

I also have a loop that gets the values of 3 variables:

```
author = gets.chomp
file = gets.chomp
time = Time.now
```

These 3 variables correspond to the 3 generations of my hash: author is the first generation variable, and is equal to a hash; file is the second generation variable, and is equal to an array; time is the third generation variable, and is equal to a simple value.

This is how I intended to assign the values to the hash:

```
hash[author][file] = file
hash[author][file].push(time)
```

My problem is that when I want to implement an author and a file in the hash, I think that I destroy the second generation hash or the array and set the variable equal to a simple value instead:

```
hash[author][file] = file      #here, instead of adding a new key in the 2nd generation hash, I replace the hash with a single value.
hash[author][file].push(time)  #the "file" variable isn't an array anymore, it is a string, so I can't push anything in it.
```

Can I do something like pushing a value in a hash, so it becomes a key?

If not, how can I have something that would give me this result:

CODE:

```
hash = {1 => {"a1" => ["un", "uno"], "a2" => ["uunn", "uunnoo"]}, 2 => {"b1" => ["deux", "dos"], "b2" => ["ddeuxx", "ddooss"]}}

hash.each do |key, value|
    puts key
    value.each do |key, value|
        puts key
        value.each do |value|
            puts value
        end
    end
end
```

RESULT:

```
1
a1
un
uno
a2
uunn
uunnoo
2
b1
deux
dos
b2
ddeuxx
ddooss
```

Comment: What does your input data look like? You don't "push" values into hashes, you just assign to them.

Comment: i add it to the post

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for a custom class or Struct. Complicated data structures using primitives like hashes and arrays are a recipe for headaches now and major headaches later.

Comment: So I see your input (hash) but I'm unclear what you want your output to be.  Given the input you gave us what should it be transformed into?

Comment: the name of the author should be in a hash, which means there can be several authors with a different name each. the name of the different files an author created should be in a hash too, since they are all unique, and as keys, they have a value, which is their date of creation. Each of these file hash should be, in the hash system, a value corresponding to one of the different keys of the first hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then setting the value to a string here:

```
hash[author][file] = file
```

You can set the string as a value of a key:

```
hash[author][file][:file] = file
```

And then let the array be another property

```
hash[author][file][:times] ||= []
hash[author][file][:times].push time
```

Comment: I think I understood of this ||= that it is something that creates a value for a variable that have none or that already have one, which would mean a hash key can have 2 (or more) values, instead of 1, am I right? If not then I don't understand your whole comment.

Strangely, I tried to use ||=, totally blindly, and... my code worked perfectly, somehow! I had no clue what happened for it to work.

Comment: if `hash[author][file]` is an empty hash, then accessing `[:times]` would be nil. `||=` sets it to a value _only if it's currently undefined or false_. So you can call `||= as many times as you want without removing elements you've stored into the array. The key here is nested data structures.